# How do I write an Excel formula to compare year-to-date to prior years & also account for leap years?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, leap-year

I’m trying to compare a measure as of today through the same day and month for the prior 4 years (e.g. through June 6 of 2016, 2015, 2014, etc.).
For each year, I decided to count the number of days since the beginning of the year, and sum my values through that number of days for each year.

To identify whether a date should be included in the year to date comparison, I used the formula where my date is in cell A1:

```
=IF((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)+1)<=(TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)+1),1,0)
```

I’m looking for a way around the issue of the extra day added to leap years.  In other words, after February 28th, the day count will always be off by one in a leap year, and trying to use Februrary 29th in a non-leap year will return an error.

I’d like to adjust this formula, but I’m open to using a different function & formula if it gets me the right results.

Comment: Warning: Not every year divisible by 4 is a leap year! Rather than focusing on days in a year why not query on "1/1/YEAR" thru Same-day-that-year?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table structure like this:

```
A:Date     | B:Value
----------------------
01/01/2016 | 0
01/01/2015 | 1
01/01/2014 | 2
01/01/2013 | 3
01/01/2012 | 4
```

## Formula

To - for example - calculate the average of the previous four (excluding the current) years on January 1st (today is 01/01/2016):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  (MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(compare))*
  (DAY(A:A)=DAY(compare))*
  (YEAR(A:A)>YEAR(compare)-5)*
  (YEAR(A:A)<YEAR(compare))*
  (B:B)
 ) / (
   SUMPRODUCT(
     (MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(compare))*
     (DAY(A:A)=DAY(compare))*
     (YEAR(A:A)>YEAR(compare)-5)*
     (YEAR(A:A)<YEAR(compare))*
     1
   )
 )
```

## Result

For the above example, the result is 2.5

## Explanation

To select only those rows representing the same month and day:

```
(MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(compare))*(DAY(A:A)=DAY(compare))
```

To select only those values from the previous 4 years (excluding the current):

```
(YEAR(A:A)>YEAR(compare)-5)*(YEAR(A:A)<YEAR(compare))*
```

The actual values we are interested in:

```
(B:B)
```

Divide by 4 for the average over the last four years. This assumes there is no missing data which might be an issue. You could use another SUMPRODUCT (replace B:B with 1) to count the number of resulting rows and divide by that number to handles this case. This seems to be rather slow, but it works.

## Note

For performance reason you should not use A:A (a full column) in the formula, just use the actual range you need, which will likely be much faster.

Comment: I don't think my initial question was very clear. The problem I'm trying to solve is the fact that the day counts diverge after Februrary 28th (day 59) for leap years and non leap years (e.g. 2/29/2012 = 60, while 2/29/2013 = ERROR, & 3/1/2012 = 61, while 3/1/2013 = 60).

Comment: And I still don't get you. As the above formula will calculate the number of days for you, working both for leap and for non leap years.

Comment: Ok, on --second-- third reading I believe I got it. Why do you want to use days as offset? Why not build a target date using DATEVALUE and only use those values having a date <= your target date? That way you get rid of the leap year/non leap year issue.

Comment: In order to compare the summed data to-date for 2012 and 2013, for instance, I need 03/01/2013 and 03/01/2012 to return the same value. Both my formula and yours return values that are 1 number off due to the extra day in the 2012 leap year. So, I guess I need to add a condition that either a. adds a 1 to all the non-leap year days from 03/01 through 12/31 or b. skips/pauses the count for any leap year's extra day, 02/29.  That way, all dates after 02/28 will return the same values for both leap years and non-leap years. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please give an example of your worksheet / data. It's hard for me to guess what the issue is.

Comment: You have the right idea about what the data looks like in your earlier example.  One column is a date, and there are several columns with values associated with each date.

Comment: I would still say you should not use day offsets as the method of choice to determine the values to use. Just rely on the dates directly as per my example. The only shortcoming I currently see with this approach is what to do if your comparison date is Feb 29th, but that's more of a business issue than a programming issues.

Comment: BTW what do you mean by compare? What is your method of comparison?

Comment: I'm comparing a measure calculated year to date from the current year to the average of the same value through the same date from the previous 4 years. It's just a straight comparison.

Comment: Ok, I updated the formula above to calculate the average over the previous 4 years. I guess you can do the comparison on your own.

Answer (score 0):

you can check any information about February, 29th. If an error occurs, you know its no leap year. Catch that error with `=IFERROR(;)`.